# How to access a web method (WebGet) from URL in the browser?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I've create a service as shown below.

```
namespace Proxy
{
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
    RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class Service
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetMessage")]
    public String GetMessage()
    {
      return "message";
    }
  }
}
```

But when I enter the url of my site with */GetMessage* added, I'm receiving a nag about the resource having been moved.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

What did I forgot to do?! It's been a while so I feel rusty. A quick googling gave me nothing that **I** realized was of help... Pointers to better search are appreciated (o, if it's something simple - a smack on the back of my head).

I've tried calling the service as follows.

1. site.azurewebsites.com/
2. site.azurewebsites.net/GetMessage
3. site.azurewebsites.net/Proxy
4. site.azurewebsites.net/Proxy?wsdl
5. site.azurewebsites.net/Proxy/GetMessage

Comment: Shouldn't the OperationContract attribute on the interface, which you registered with WCF for the service? Or have you added to code above, just to keep it compact? I could be wrong.. but I've always seen the contract defined with interface, not directly on the class.

Comment: Not sure. It's what I got from the template stright-out-of-the-box... Still, the question remains - am I calling the service method in the correct way?!

Comment: How are you registering the service with WCF? through code or from .svc file hosted in IIS? Can you share that code / details as well? Sounds like what you type in browser and what is registered don't match.. except for my comment above, about interface, I don't see anything wrong with the code in service class.

Comment: I upload the stuff to the Azure using the publish file of the lazy man (downloaded from the Azure site, hehe).

Comment: If fine to be lazy and use VS to publish.. but I assume then, your site is hosted in IIS.. is there a .svc file in your project? lets say foo.svc. If yes, then try `site.azurewebsites.com/foo.svc/GetMessage` If it works, let me know, and I'll add the answer you can then accept :)

Comment: Nope... "I get Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ScriveProxy.svc/GetListOfTemplates"